# Hilbert basis of the tensor product $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

Let it be $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ two separable complex Hilbert spaces. The algebraic tensor product is defined as:

$\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2=\{\sum_{k=0}^n v_k \otimes w_k \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, v_k \in \mathcal{H}_1, w_k \in \mathcal{H}_2\}$

We endowed $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$ with the inner product:

$\langle u \mid z \rangle=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{h=0}^m \langle v_k \mid v_h' \rangle\langle w_k \mid w_h' \rangle, \quad u=\sum_{k=0}^n v_k \otimes w_k, \quad z=\sum_{h=0}^m v_h' \otimes w_h'$.

Then $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$ becomes a pre-Hilbert space.

The tensor product $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2=\overline{\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2}$ is the completion of $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$ with respect to the topology induced by the inner product on $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$. Clearly $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$ is a complex Hilbert space.

Now consider $\{\xi_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $\{\eta_j\}_{j \in J}$ two countable Hilbert basis respectively of $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$. I want to show that $\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is a Hilbert basis of $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

$ $

My attempt:

Obviously $\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is an orthonormal system. We have to show that it is even complete.

Given $\{v_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{H}_1$ and $\{w_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{H}_2$ such that $v_n \to v \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $w_n \to w \in \mathcal{H}_2$, then we can easily show that $v_n \otimes w_n \to v \otimes w$. Then, using bilinearity and continuity of $\otimes$, we have:

$(\sum_{i \in I} a_i\xi_i) \otimes (\sum_{j \in J} b_j\eta_j)=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} a_ib_j(\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)$.

Then take $u \in \mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$. We have:

$u=\sum_{k=0}^n v_k \otimes w_k=\sum_{k=0}^n (\sum_{i \in I} a_i^k\xi_i) \otimes (\sum_{j \in J} b_j^k\eta_j)=$

$=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} a_i^kb_j^k (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij} (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)$,

with $c_{ij}=\sum_{k=0}^na_i^kb_j^k \in \mathbb{C}$. Then every element $u$ of $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$ can be written this way.

[From this point actually I have found a better way to prove the statement, see the EDIT below]

Now fix the sequence:

$\{u_n=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij}^n (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$.

Suppose that this sequence converges to $u$ ($u$ in not necessarily in $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$, since it is not complete), namely $u_n \to u$. By definition, clearly $u \in \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$. It is clear that $u$ is the most generic element of $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$, so if we can show that $u$ can be written as $u=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} d_{ij} (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)$ we have reached our goal. We have that:

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} u_n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} c_{ij}^n (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} (\lim_{n \to +\infty} c_{ij}^n) (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)$.

Then it follows that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} c_{ij}^n \equiv d_{ij}$ must exists, and:

$u=\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} d_{ij} (\xi_i \otimes \eta_j)$.

So we can conclude that $\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}$ is a Hilbert basis of $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

$ $

**My question is: is my approach correct? Maybe it is not so much rigorous, but is it at least correct? Thank you!**

$ $

EDIT

I think that what follows makes my proof rigorous. I clearly have proved that:

$\mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2 \subseteq \overline{\text{Span}(\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J})}$.

Then it follows that:

$\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2 \subseteq \overline{\text{Span}(\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J})}$.

We have also that:

$\text{Span}(\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J}) \subseteq \mathcal{H}_1 \odot \mathcal{H}_2$,

then:

$\overline{\text{Span}(\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J})} \subseteq \mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

Finally:

$\overline{\text{Span}(\{\xi_i \otimes \eta_j\}_{(i,j) \in I \times J})}=\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes \mathcal{H}_2$.

Comment: I think the line where you exchange the limes and the series is highly unrigorous, yes. So why can you conclude that $c_{ij}^n$ converges?

Comment: @hal4math By definition $c_{ij}^n=\sum_{k=0}^m \langle \xi_i \mid v_k^n \rangle\langle \eta_j \mid w_k^n \rangle$. Maybe we can use the continuity of the inner product and conclude that $\sum_{k=0}^m \langle \xi_i \mid v_k^n \rangle\langle \eta_j \mid w_k^n \rangle \to \sum_{k=0}^m \langle \xi_i \mid v_k \rangle\langle \eta_j \mid w_k \rangle$, but first we have to assume that $v_k^n \to v_k$ and that $w_k^n \to w_k$. So I really don't know, to be honest. Any hint maybe?

Comment: A much simpler approach is to show that the linear span of the $\xi_i\otimes\eta_j$ is dense in $H_1\otimes H_2$.  This is another characterization of Hilbert bases.

Comment: @Ruy Yes, you are right, I have had your same idea at the same moment :), in fact I have just edited my question.

Comment: I think that looks about right. Also notice that in that case you don't need the part where you exchange the limes and the series.